# Filtering datatables with checkbox and keeping state on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, datatables

I have a datatable whose columns can be filtered with a checkbox. When the checkbox is checked the column is displayed, if unchecked the column is hidden. I am trying to save the state of the checkboxes (i.e., checked or unchecked) on page refresh, which does work (i.e., the boxes that were checked are still checked on refresh, the boxes not checked are not). Unfortunately, this seems to have no impact on whether the columns are shown. So, if the checkbox is clicked on, the column is shown, and if clicked on again (unchecked) the column is not shown. Upon refresh the checkbox states are the same, but the columns are no longer impacted. I am trying to figure out not only how to save the status of the checkboxes, but also to save the effects that those checkboxes have (show column or not) on page refresh.

Here is what the checkboxes look like (note that I have added checked to the checkboxes to display the default behavior of the datatable):

```
<label for="address" class="label">Name
  <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="pname" id="pname" onclick="fnShowHide(0);" checked>
</label>
<label for="address" class="label">Address
  <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="address" id="address" onclick="fnShowHide(1);" checked>
</label>
<label for="address" class="label">City
  <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="city" id="city" onclick="fnShowHide(2);" checked>
</label>
<label for="address" class="label">State
  <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="state" id="state" onclick="fnShowHide(3);" checked>
</label>
<label for="address" class="label">DOB
  <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="dob" id="dob" onclick="fnShowHide(4);" checked>
</label>
<label for="address" class="label">Occupation
  <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="occupation" id="occupation" onclick="fnShowHide(5);">
</label>
<label for="address" class="label">Vehicle Type
  <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="vehicle_type" id="vehicle_type" onclick="fnShowHide(6);" checked>
</label>
```

Here is what the datatable looks like (with the ShowHide Function):

```
var table = $('#people');
    table.dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 500,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "aLengthMenu": [[-1, 25, 50, 100], ["All", 25, 50, 100]],
        'aoColumns': [
                /* Name */ null,
                /* Address */ null,
                /* City */ null,
                /* State */           null,
                /* DOB */            { "bSortable": false },
                /* Occupation */     { "bVisible":    false },
                /* Vehicle Type */   { "bVisible":    false }
        ],
        'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
        'sDom': '<"dataTables_header"lfr>t<"dataTables_footer"ip>',
        'fnInitComplete': function( oSettings )
        { 
          table.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_length select').addClass('select blue-gradient glossy').styleSelect();
          tableStyled = true;
        }
    });

    function fnShowHide( iCol )
    {
        /* Get the DataTables object again - this is not a recreation, just a get of the object */
        var oTable = $('#people').dataTable();

        var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
        oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
    }
```

And here is the function I am using to keep the state of the checkboxes:

```
$("input.box").each(function() {
        var mycookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('name'));
        if (mycookie && mycookie == "true") {
            $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
        }
    });
    $("input.box").change(function() {
        $.cookie($(this).attr("name"), $(this).prop('checked'), {
        path: '/',
        expires: 365
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if the cookies are actually set in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call your showhide function when restoring from cookies:

```
$("input.box").each(function( idx ) {
    var mycookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('name'));
    if (mycookie && mycookie == "true") {
        $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
        fnShowHide(idx);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am accepting this answer, though I am unable to upvote (not enough rep), nor does it seem that I can nominate this as an answer. Anyway, the problem was actually that I was not including jquery.cookie.js. However, your answer was also helpful in that I created a function to show the column when restoring from cookies on reload and called that function just as you've suggested. Thank you!